# How to make multiple random alphanumeric strings with one const array in a node.js discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am really stuck, and I need help answering how to generate new random strings from my bot, so far this is the code when a user type %random

```
// Dependencies
const { MessageEmbed, Message } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../config.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'random', // Command name
    description: 'Generate a random alphanumeric string.', // Command description

    /**
     * Command exetute
     * @param {Message} message The message sent by user
     */
    execute(message) {
    
    if (message.channel.id !== config.stringChannel) {
        message.channel.send(
            new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(config.color.default)
            .setTitle('Wrong Channel')
            .setDescription('Go to '+`<#${config.stringChannel}>`+' to generate nitro') // Mapping the commands
            .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 64 }))
            .setTimestamp()
        );
    };
    const gn = [`${Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)}`+'\n'];
    if (message.channel.id === config.stringChannel) {
              message.channel.send(
            new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(config.color.default)
            .setTitle(`String Generated`)
            .setDescription(`${gn}${gn}`) // Mapping the commands
            .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 64 }))
            .setTimestamp()
        );
    }
}
};
```

The following picture is the resulting embedded message I receive when I send %random
[received embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcv5y.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `function` and `forlooping`

```js
function generateAlpaNum(number) { //the number is your given number.
    var emptyString = ""; //To fill up the empty string when generating.
    var AlphaNumeric = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //your AN
    var ANLength = AlphaNumeric.length; //Getting the length
    for(var i = 0; i < number; i++) { //loop when given number doesnt matched with I
        emptyString += AlphaNumeric.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ANLength));  //Filling the emptyString
    }

    return emptyString;
}

console.log(generateAlpaNum(5));
```

You can check the snippet to see the result:

```js
function generateAlpaNum(number) { //the number is your given number.
    var emptyString = ""; //To fill up the empty string when generating.
    var AlphaNumeric = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //your AN
    var ANLength = AlphaNumeric.length; //Getting the length
    for(var i = 0; i < number; i++) { //loop when given number doesnt matched with I
        emptyString += AlphaNumeric.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ANLength));  //Filling the emptyString
    }

    return emptyString;
}

console.log(generateAlpaNum(5));
```

You can also check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duLy7emn/) to see the live code.

This is the proof for working function with `node.js`:
[image: The source Code of mine]

Result:

[image: Result for the source code]

Comment: This web javascript does not work with node.js, because functions do not work the same way, for example your code does work, but if implemented would fail because of undefined variable "function"

Comment: It will work, I always use it for my other command such as `generateKeyCode` or smthing

Comment: @Altify NodeJS is Chrome's V8 engine running outside a web browser, it's the same JavaScript. It is merely a superset of Vanilla JavaScript

Comment: Wasn't working with my discord bot, but it is working code.

Answer (score 0):

I found working code for what I wanted to make, here it is

```
const gn = [""];
let cap = 100
for (let i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
gn.push("");
};


let text = "";
let fLen = gn.length;
for (let i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += gn[i] +`${Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)}`+'\n';
}
    if (message.channel.id === config.stringChannel) {
              message.channel.send(
            new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(config.color.default)
            .setTitle(`String Generated`)
            .setDescription(`${text}`) // Mapping the commands
            .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 64 }))
            .setTimestamp()
        );
    }
```

Comment: You just use different  format, but if its working then its okay.